# Python Pandas using lambda on index row by row

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

So I'm trying to apply a function to the index row by row but having some problems

```
startDate = '2015-05-01 00:00'
endDate = '2015-05-08 00:00'
idx = pd.date_range(startDate, endDate, freq="1min")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['F(t)'])
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

def circadian_function(T):
    return math.cos(math.pi*(T-delta)/12)
```

Everything is okay up to here but trying to apply the function I'm not sure what to do

```
df['F(t)'] = df.index.apply(lambda x: circadian_function x[index].hour, axis=1)
```

Should I be using a lambda? Or just an apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have 50 rep so I can't comment on @Ted Petrou's answer ;-;
I just wanted to say a couple things that you should know.

1. If you are going to feed `df.index.hour` into your carcadian_function, make sure you use `numpy` instead of `math`. Otherwise the interpreter will throw a `TypeError` (I just found out about this).
2. Make sure to define `delta`.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

def circadian_function(T, delta):
    return np.cos(np.pi * (T-delta) / 12)
```

What @Ted Petrou recommends you do in full:

```
df['F(x)'] = circadian_function(df.index.hour, 0.5) #I picked an arbitrary delta
```

Numpy will automatically vectorize the function for you. Props to Ted I learned something new as well :>

Comment: forget about the delta, i define delta=18 in the code, but df['F(x)'] = circadian_function(df.index.hour) gives the error TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: That's exactly why you should change `math` to `numpy`, or `np` in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Use apply only as a last result. This can be easily vectorized. Make sure you define delta.

```
 import numpy as np
 df['F(t)'] = np.cos(np.pi*(idx.hour-delta)/12)
```

Comment: what do you mean? this df['F(t)'] = df.apply(math.cos(math.pi*(idx.hour-delta)/12)) does not work (even after defining delta)

Comment: and this does not work either df['F(t)'] = df['F(t)'].apply(math.cos(math.pi*(df.index.hour-delta)/12))

Comment: and this also does not work df['F(t)'] = df.index.apply(math.cos(math.pi*(idx.hour-delta)/12))

Comment: does anyone else know how to provide a working answer to this question?

Comment: Try it now. I added the dt accessor

Comment: it does not work still, df['F(t)'] = df.index.apply(math.cos(math.pi*(idx.dt.hour-delta)/12)) gives the error AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'apply'